# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'generate_tokens'

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a=np.random.randint(10,size=(2,2))
np.save('dd', a)
```

This is my code, seems pretty easy, but get following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\py\Pwork1\src\tttttt.py", line 333, in <module>
    np.savez('a',a)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 593, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 665, in _savez
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 555, in write_array
    version)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 314, in _write_array_header
    header = asbytes(_filter_header(header))
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 450, in _filter_header
    for token in tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO(asstr(s)).read):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'generate_tokens'
```

It's definitely not because I have a generate_tokens.py or tokenize.py. And I checked the tokenize and it clearly has generate_tokens.

Comment: If you add two lines to your code: `import tokenize` and then `print(tokenize)`, and then run your code in the same way as before, what output do you see from that `print` statement?

Comment: <module 'tokenize' from 'D:\Anaconda\lib\tokenize.pyc'>

Comment: @MarkDickinson  i get this